# Customise SQL Compare script output for Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

We've recently started using Database Projects in Visual Studio 2013.  So far, it's great!

There are some things we'd like to be able to customise and I'm not sure if it's even possible.

We'd like to be able to have our post-deployment scripts appended to the SQL that is generated when doing a schema compare, so that when we create a deployment script, it comes with our post-deployment stuff all in the one .sql file.  Is there a way to do that?

Also, we'd like to know if there's a way that the .sql file that is generated can be customised (much like a .tt file can be for entity framework).

Comment: .tt files are supported. You can add either a regular T4 or a SQL specific T4 template via Add -> New Item -> Text Template or Text Template (Transact-SQL Template). Search for SSDT T4 for examples - http://dataidol.com/davebally/2014/03/29/t4-support-in-ssdt/ is a good place to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SSDT!

Pre/Post deploy scripts don't get used by the schema compare so if you generate a lot of scripts then set up PowerShell or a batch file to call sqlpackage.exe and set the action to script. I use this as part of a CI build to generate scripts for different environments and works great.

You can customize the output by choosing what to include or exclude in the output script but if there is something not supplied out of the box you can modify it by using deployment contributors which you can add or remove steps or do things like add your own transactions etc, for more details see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial.aspx

If you let us know more about how you want to change it, there may be something already available to help.

Ed